# How to map a nested object to another existing object of the same type?

Tags: automapper

There are two classes:

```
public class Foo
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
}


public class FooWrapper
{
    public Foo Foo { get; set; }
}
```

The goal is to map FooWrapper to Foo.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void FooWrapperDerived_CanBeAssignToFoo_WithoutAfterMap()
    {
        FooWrapper fw = new FooWrapper { Foo = new Foo { Name = "foo" } };
        Foo foo = new Foo();

        Mapper.CreateMap<Foo, Foo>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<FooWrapper, Foo>();
            //.ConstructUsing(w => w.Foo);                      //Actual:<(null)>
            //.ConvertUsing(w => w.Foo);                        //Actual:<(null)>
            //.ForAllMembers(c => c.MapFrom(w => w.Foo));       //Actual:<MvcArch.Tests.Common.Foo>
            //.ForAllMembers(c => c.ResolveUsing(w => w.Foo));  //Actual:<MvcArch.Tests.Common.Foo>
            //.ForAllMembers(c => c.UseValue(fw.Foo));          //Actual:<MvcArch.Tests.Common.Foo>
            //.ForMember(f => f, c => c.MapFrom(w => w.Foo));   //AutoMapper configuration exception
            //.ForMember(f => f.Name, c => c.ResolveUsing(w => w.Foo)); //Actual:<MvcArch.Tests.Common.Foo>
            //.ForMember(f => f.Name, c => c.MapFrom(w => w.Foo.Name)); //works, but I don't want to repeat each property in the configuration

        Mapper.Map<FooWrapper, Foo>(fw, foo);   //uses the Map defined for the base type FooWrapper

        Assert.AreNotSame(foo, fw.Foo);
        Assert.AreEqual("foo", foo.Name);
    }
```

It works using AfterMap as:
    Mapper.CreateMap().AfterMap((w, f) => Mapper.Map(w.Foo, f));
but is it possible to define the map without accessing the global Mapper object?

Comment: Why do you need FooWrapper? Is it for applying some conditions on mapping?

Comment: @k0stya In real, FooWrapper is a viewmodel that contains an entity (foo) with some additional properties.

Comment: If there is not condition depending on FooWrapper then I'd suggest to map directly fw.Foo -> Foo

Comment: What version of AutoMapper are you using? `ConstructUsing` seems to work for me with 2.0

Comment: @Whitaker  ConstructUsing Creates a new object while I want to assign property values to an existing object. Ther Version is the most recently checked by nuGet